# How to see 'syslog' output at app_server running PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm testing a PHP application at my computer using the app_server launched by "Google App Engine Launcher".

But, at its logs, I am not seeing the output from the syslogs that are inserted at my PHP code.

I've tried the parameters --log_level and --dev_appserver_log_level without any success.

Do anybody knows what can be done?

My Google App Engine Launcher is version 1.8.6.

Comment: Having the same problem. Did not find any solution. I help myself by writing things in memcache:

`$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->set('log_1', print_r($var, true));
`

Comment: You can save logs on disk with simple function file_put_contents()

Answer (score 1):

The default configuration should have syslogging enabled so no additional parameters should be necessary when launching app_server. Could you execute a very simple test script and post the output?

```
<?php
print 'Using syslog() '. (syslog(LOG_DEBUG, 'Testing syslog() functionality') ? 'succeeded' : 'failed');
```

After executing the above script and getting a positive result message you should find at least one entry in your local syslog.

If you want to read the logs programmatically (source [1]):

you can iterate over messages added by `syslog()` using AppEngine's `LogService` API:

```
use google\appengine\api\log\LogService;
use google\appengine\util as util;

$start = (float) $_GET["start"];
$end = (float) $_GET["end"];

$options = [
  'start_time' => $start * 1e6,
  'end_time' => $end * 1e6,
  'include_app_logs' => true
];

$logs = LogService::fetch($options);
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/logs/